# select xsl:variable values of its child-nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, libreoffice-calc

I have an .ods file and want to access the values of `table-cell`s in `table-row`s by the value of the first column for the given row. So their heading in my case.

So the calc table looks like this:

```
First_Name | Last_Name
Peter      | Parker
Emma       | Stone
...
```

Here is my xslt-export-filter file:

*SuperBasicExportFilter.xslt*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
  xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
  xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="table text office"
>

  <xsl:output
    method="xml"
    indent="yes"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
  />

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="columnHeadings">
      <xsl:for-each select="//table:table/table:table-row[not(preceding::table:table-row)]//table:table-cell">
        <xsl:element name="heading">
          <xsl:attribute name="name" select="text:p" />
          <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <html>
      <body>

      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <xsl:message>columnHeadings: <xsl:value-of select="$columnHeadings" /></xsl:message>

      <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="//table:table/table:table-row">

          <xsl:if test="position() > 1">

            <tr>
              <td>
                First Column Value
                <xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[1]/text:p" />
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[$columnHeadings/heading[@name='First_Name']]/text:p" /> -->
              </td>
              <td>
                Second Column Value
                <xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[2]/text:p" />
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[$columnHeadings/heading[@name='Last_Name']]/text:p" /> -->
              </td>
            </tr>

          </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
    </html>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The message shows "columnHeadings: 1234567891011121314" and so on. So it is setting the position values correctly.

I tried getting the values based on the "name" attribute on the "heading" element.
But I can't get the values individually in any way. It seems I can't use the $columnHeadings with any XPath expression. It just returns "Xpath evaluation returned no result".

I tried

- wrapping the "heading" elements with a "columnHeadings" element inside the variable and setting the "as" value of the variable to "element()"
- using the "node-set" function (after importing the "exslt" ns)
- using `<xsl:variable name="columnHeadingsNode" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name = 'columnHeadings']" />` to then get the value
- using the `xsl:key` element like `<xsl:key name="columnHeadings" match="//table:table/table:table-row[not(preceding::table:table-row)]//table:table-cell" use="text:p" />`  - but this way I can't access it based on the "name"

What other things can I try to access the variable contents with a xpath expression?

Is it even possible to access the values like `table:table-cell[$columnHeadings/heading[@name='Last_Name']]`?

---

Answers to comments:

> Which XSLT processor are you using?

I'm using whatever libreoffice 7.4.5.1 is using.
Can I change that?
The xsl:vendor is "libxslt" and the version is "1.0" according to the `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>` and `xsl:version` values.

> Do you get an error on `<xsl:attribute name="name" select="text:p" />`?

I actually do not for some reason. The test runs through without errors. I get a new browser tab with the produced xml output and no errors.

I tried ticking the "The filter needs XSLT 2.0 processor" but then I can't test run the filter anymore and don't get any output.

> What's the overall purpose of this exercise?

I want to be able to select the values in the columns by their respective column heading, instead of the index, because I want to make it as portable as possible. At least I think that would help to achieve that goal. I have 184 columns. The column names won't change as likely as the index of the column, I believe.

**SOLVED**

My working file looks like this now:

*SuperBasicExportFilter.xslt*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
  xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
  xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="table text office exsl"
>

  <xsl:output
    method="xml"
    indent="yes"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
  />

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="columnHeadings-temp" xmlns="">
      <xsl:for-each select="//table:table/table:table-row[not(preceding::table:table-row)]//table:table-cell">
        <xsl:element name="heading">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl value-of select="normalize-space(text:p)" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="columnHeadings" select="exsl:node-set($columnHeadings-temp)" />

    <html>
      <body>
      <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="//table:table/table:table-row">

          <xsl:if test="position() > 1">

            <tr>
              <td>
                First Column Value
                <xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[number($columnHeadings/heading[@name='First_Name'])]/text:p" />
              </td>
              <td>
                Second Column Value
                <xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[number($columnHeadings/heading[@name='Last_Name'])]/text:p" />
              </td>
            </tr>

          </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
    </html>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: With an XSLT 1.0 processor your variable is a result tree fragment (RTF), either switch to an XSLT 2 or 3 processor (like Saxon HE (latest stable version 11.5)) or find out which XSLT 1.0 processor you are using and which kind of extension function like `exsl:node-set` it supports to convert a result tree fragment into a node-set.

Comment: Do you get an error on `<xsl:attribute name="name" select="text:p" />`? Any XSLT 1.0 processor with `version="1.0"` should throw an error as XSLT 1.0 didn't allow a `select` attribute on `xsl:attribute`.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/75514330/3016153. Note that the `libxslt` processor supports a number of extension functions, among them `str:tokenize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent `<xsl:attribute name="name" select="text:p" />` fails to create an attribute with a value in XSLT 1; it should raise an error but it seems your XSLT processor kind of ignores the `select`.

So try

```
<xsl:attribute name="name">
   <xsl:value-of select="text:p"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

instead.

That way, I would think that e.g. `<xsl:variable name="columnHeadings-ns" select="exsl:node-set($columnHeadings)" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>` should allow you to use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[$columnHeadings-ns/heading[@name='First_Name']]/text:p"/>`.

Comment: I had to wrap the index from the `$columnHeadings` in a call to `number` like this `<xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[number($columnHeadings-ns/heading[@name='First_Name'])]/text:p"/>`. My guess is the `node-set` function converted it to a string.