# Reorder table columns

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Following [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75498989/3016153), I was looking for a more general solution to the problem of rearranging table columns in custom order (given by column names). I couldn't find any, so I am posting mine here.

**Input XML**

```
<table>
    <row>
        <cell>NAME</cell>
        <cell>DATE</cell>
        <cell>SIZE</cell>
        <cell>COLOR</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Alpha</cell>
        <cell>2023-02-19</cell>
        <cell>Small</cell>
        <cell>Red</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Bravo</cell>
        <cell>2023-02-19</cell>
        <cell>Small</cell>
        <cell>Green</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Charlie</cell>
        <cell>2023-02-19</cell>
        <cell>Small</cell>
        <cell>Blue</cell>
    </row>
</table>
```

**Expected output**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>COLOR</th>
        <th>SIZE</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2023-02-19</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Small</td>
        <td>Alpha</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2023-02-19</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Small</td>
        <td>Bravo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2023-02-19</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>Small</td>
        <td>Charlie</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 1.0 (with EXSLT node-set() extension function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="new-order">DATE,COLOR,SIZE,NAME</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:variable name="columns-RTF">
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-columns">
            <xsl:with-param name="headings" select="$new-order"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="top-row-cells" select="row[1]/cell"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="exsl:node-set($columns-RTF)/column" />
    <!-- output -->
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>   
        <!-- data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row[position() > 1]">
            <tr>
                <xsl:variable name="cells" select="cell" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$cells[position() = current()/@i]" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-columns">
    <xsl:param name="headings"/>
    <xsl:param name="top-row-cells"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($headings, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <column i="{count($top-row-cells[. = $token]/preceding-sibling::cell) + 1}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
    </column>
    <xsl:if test="contains($headings, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-columns">
            <xsl:with-param name="headings" select="substring-after($headings, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="top-row-cells" select="$top-row-cells"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

With a processor that supports a `tokenize()` extension function, this could be reduced to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" 
extension-element-prefixes="exsl str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="new-order">DATE,COLOR,SIZE,NAME</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:variable name="top-row-cells" select="row[1]/cell"/>
    <xsl:variable name="columns-RTF">
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($new-order, ',')">
            <column i="{count($top-row-cells[. = current()]/preceding-sibling::cell) + 1}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </column>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="exsl:node-set($columns-RTF)/column" />
    <!-- output -->
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>   
        <!-- data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row[position() > 1]">
            <tr>
                <xsl:variable name="cells" select="cell" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$cells[position() = current()/@i]" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="new-order">DATE,COLOR,SIZE,NAME</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:variable name="top-row-cells" select="row[1]/cell" />
    <xsl:variable name="columns" as="element()*">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($new-order, ',')">
            <column i="{index-of($top-row-cells, .)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </column>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>   
        <!-- data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row[position() > 1]">
            <tr>
                <xsl:variable name="cells" select="cell" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$cells[position() = current()/@i]" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3, using static parameters and shadow attributes, you can try to make it generic to deal with different kind of table/row/cell vocabularies:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="table-el-name" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'table'"/>
<xsl:param name="table-row-name" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'row'"/>
<xsl:param name="table-cell-name" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'cell'"/>

<xsl:param name="new-order">DATE,COLOR,SIZE,NAME</xsl:param>

<xsl:template _match="{$table-el-name}">
    <xsl:variable name="top-row-cells" _select="{$table-row-name}[1]/{$table-cell-name}" />
    <xsl:variable name="columns" as="element()*">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($new-order, ',')">
            <column i="{index-of($top-row-cells, .)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </column>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>   
        <!-- data -->
        <xsl:for-each _select="{$table-row-name}[position() > 1]">
            <tr>
                <xsl:variable name="cells" _select="{$table-cell-name}"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$cells[position() = current()/@i]" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```